# Using EC2 for validation testing

Tags: testing, internationalization, amazon-ec2

I've got a desktop application that I need to test in several different languages. I could build a VMWare image for each language that I need. But I was wondering if I could somehow use EC2 instead.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825023/amazon-ec2-usable-as-a-vmware-testing-platform), but it is asking about running VMWare in EC2. I want to know if I can use EC2 instead of VMWare.

What kind of interface do you get to the EC2 instances? Can you install applications easily? Are there windows instances available in a variety of languages, include Turkish, Chinese, and Korean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon doesn't offer non-English versions of Windows; they also only offer Windows Server 2003 and 2008, which may not be what you need.  I think you'd be better off using multiple instances of VMware installed locally.